# How to segment individiual books in an image of a bookshelf

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation

[image: a bookshelf]

When you photograph a bookshelf, the spines of the books appear as rectangles (more or less). I am trying to segment images of books in a bookshelf(, and later compare them to my dataset of book images.)

As can be seen in the above image, the individual book spines can be separated by their different color, shadows (between two books), and sometimes texture. The books in the provided image are set rather tidy, but books can sometimes lean on other books; so their spine "rectangles" may have any orientation. Also, some books have rectangles printed on their spine! So they may be segmented as little books by mistake.

What is the best approach to segmenting the books? In other words, how can I detect rectangles of various size, color and texture?

Answer (score 1):

You could segment your image in superpixels (I recommend using [SLIC](http://www.kev-smith.com/papers/SLIC_Superpixels.pdf) [1] which is available in OpenCV), extract superpixel information and classify them based on this to obtain the final segmentation.

The superpixel should adhere to the books border, creating the desired rectangles.

The superpixel coordinates and texture/color is going to help you merge superpixels, for distinct books this might do the trick of segmenting them completely.

1. Achanta, Radhakrishna, et al. Slic superpixels. No. EPFL-REPORT-149300. 2010.

Comment: What about books that have textures with many colors and shapes? Or those that have, lets say, a black top-half and a white bottom-half?

Comment: Your knowledge about the book displacement will be necessary to build this classifier (when I say classifier I don't mean just using an SVM implementation).

Comment: For example, you could first detect the shelf and crop each one in a separated image, with this you have a boundary where your books will be. You know that two books won't be above each other if they are on the vertical position, etc. Now the process of detecting books can be done by fitting rectangles on the segmented superpixels. I think your prior knowledge to the image is key to developing a good classifier.

Comment: While this may work for a specific image of a bookshelf, I'm looking for a more robust solution to this problem. I 'm updating my question and adding some additional info.